# Mac OS X: How to resize a window by dragging from the left side

Tags: macos, window, osx-tiger

On Solaris you can change the size of a window from the left or right side.  I am back to using Mac OS X but it is driving me nuts how you can only change the size of the window from the right side.  Is there a way to change this?  Did some searching but I just got "windows stuff".

Running Mac OS X 10.4.11.

Comment: this isn't really a question about solaris so i removed the [solaris] tag...

Comment: Even worse: just the right *bottom*...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there no window borders, this isn't an option.

There are [ways of programmatically resizing windows with applescript](http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20080523040419784). Or perhaps it bothers you enough that this little utility might be of use:

http://coderage-software.com/zooom/index_green/index.html

I've never tried it, but it looks to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're still using 10.4 there's a slim chance that there may be a ShapeShifter theme that draws window borders with handles, but the OS doesn't do it on its own.